# ASP.NET Web API Help Page Link to a Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API project (4.5) that has all the DTO objects stored in a separate project for simplicity.  I was wondering if there is anyway to link from the [Web API help page](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.helppage) to these class libraries so that my end users can not only see what they need to send but so that they can see the XML comments on those objects specifying what each property of the object does/means.

Comment: Currently this feature is not supported out of the box. There is a related workitem for this: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/877, after which your scenario should also be working. That said it should not stop you from developing your solution for this though as all HelpPag source code is available to you when you install the nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are talking on "WCF Web API Test Client",

AFAIK it uses Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.dll provided by Microsoft. The sources are not available but if it is not obfuscated you can change it after ILSPY.

Beside this you can't decorate it, normally you just redirect the page from global.asax.

Another option : Maybe you should write your own. But you will have much work with attribute reading and reflection :) Maybe you should start a project in CodePlex & git.